# Need help with jQuery syntax to change URL

Tags: jquery, facebook, lint

Using jQuery, is there a way I can make every http://www.mywebsite.com/page/ become http://www.mywebsite.com/#page for the visitors and make sure the Facebook URL Linter (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) is still able to read the tags in http://www.mywebsite.com/page/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    var pieces = location.href.split('/');
    if (pieces[3].indexOf('#!') !== 0) {
        if (location.href.indexOf('#!') != -1) {
            pieces = location.href.replace('#!','').split('/');
        }
        pieces[3] = '#!/'+pieces[3];
        location.href = pieces.join('/');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  A client-side library cannot change the path part of the URL without causing the browser to fetch a different page from the server.

So, if the user goes to http://www.mywebsite.com/page/, then you could use client-side javascript to redirect the user to http://www.mywebsite.com/#page/, but that would cause the browser to load the page http://www.mywebsite.com/ and then try to find the #page fragment in that page.  If you want the browser to reload http://www.mywebsite.com/#page/, then that is indeed what would happen.

FB will not run javascript on your page so if FB goes to http://www.mywebsite.com/page/, that's what it will see (it will not get redirected like a regular browser would).

If you want to do a forceful redirect with javascript, you can put this code in your page:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (path.search(/^\/page\/?$/) >= 0) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.mywebsite.com/#page/");
}
```

This code tests to see if the pathname on the URL of the page is `/page` or `/page/` and if so, then does the redirect.

Comment: Well I want the visitors to be redirect to and to see the content of http://www.mywebsite.com/#page/ when they type or click on a link pointing to http://www.mywebsite.com/page/ I would only like the facebook linter to see the content of http://www.mywebsite.com/page in order to read the Open Graph meta tags it contains.

Comment: Then, implement a javascript redirect from http://www.mywebsite.com/page/ to http://www.mywebsite.com#page.  FB will not execute the Javascript so it will not redirect - the user's browser will do the redirect (and their page will flash to new content during the redirect).  FYI, you may want to check the FB terms of service.  Google would consider this "cloaking" which means offering a different page to Google vs. to a user.  Cloaking sites are penalized on Google.

Comment: Yes ok, but like I said in the title I need help with the syntax ;-)

Comment: It means that page1 is a page name (pathname?) that changes depending on the name of the page the user is visiting.

Comment: I did not write it that way as you had never mentioned that as a requirement.